# preg_match any character returns false

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to match a serial looking like this: ABC-.
Using regex
Using expresso to test my regular expression, I can see that

ABC-1 (ofcourse) matches
ABC-2
ABC-!
ABC-D
ABC-z
...

However when I specify

```
preg_match('ABC-.', 'ABC-1')
```

a false boolean is returned

changing the regex to

> ABC-.

or

> ABC-.

returns false aswell, can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to activate error reporting and/or look at your error logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [required regex delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
preg_match('/ABC-./', 'ABC-1')
```

Comment: +1 beat me by 6 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, You have also beaten me several times :)

Comment: lovely, that did the trick :)

Comment: Great to know. Please consider marking it as "accepted" whenever you can.